# Undesired scrolling in React on rendering component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where the search results of a query are displayed. When clicking on a item to view its details, instead of loading normally (scrolled all the way up), the details page is, somehow, being affected by the scroll position of the results page. I know I could probably solve this by including `window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0 })`, but I just want it to behave normally like it should and eliminate what's causing this issue.

**Results.js**

```
function Results() {
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(max-width:767px)");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [details, setDetails] = useState({ results: [] });

  // Create a custom hook that binds to the `search` property from `location` url object
  function useQuery() {
    const { search } = useLocation();

    return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
  }

  let query = useQuery().toString();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });

    // On successful response, assign the results to `results` array in `details` object
    axios
      .get(`/api/results/${query}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setDetails(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [query]);

  const results = details.total_results;
  const pages = details.total_pages;
  const baseURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154";
  const placeholderImg =
    "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg";

  return (
    <CustomCard
      title="Results"
      content={
        <div>
          <Grid container>
            <Typography>{results ? results : 0} results found</Typography>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <List sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                {details.results.map((result) => {
                  return (
                    <ResultItem
                      key={result.id}
                      id={result.id}
                      imgURL={
                        result.poster_path
                          ? baseURL + result.poster_path
                          : placeholderImg
                      }
                      title={result.title}
                      year={result.release_date}
                      synopsis={result.overview}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </List>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Pagination
            sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            count={pages}
            siblingCount={matches ? 0 : 1}
            onChange={(event, page) => {
              const url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
              url.set("page", page);
              const query = url.toString();

              navigate(`/results?${query}`);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      }
    />
  );
}

export default Results;
```

**ResultItems.jsx**

```
function ResultItem(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(max-width:767px)");

  return (
    <div>
      <ListItem disablePadding>
        <ListItemButton alignItems="flex-start" sx={{ pl: 0, pt: 2 }}>
          <div>
            <img
              src={props.imgURL}
              alt={`${props.title} poster`}
              style={
                matches
                  ? { width: "80px", height: "120px" }
                  : { width: "154px", height: "231px" }
              }
            />
          </div>
          <ListItemText
            sx={{ ml: 3 }}
            primary={props.title}
            secondary={
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography component="span" variant="body2">
                  {props.year.slice(0, 4)}
                </Typography>
                <br />
                <br />
                {matches ? null : (
                  <span style={{ textAlign: "justify" }}>{props.synopsis}</span>
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            }
            onClick={() => navigate(`/details/${props.id}`)}
          />
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResultItem;
```

**Details.js**

```
function Details() {
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(max-width:718px)");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    tmdbDetails: { genres: [] },
    tmdbCredits: { cast: [], crew: [] },
    userData: { rating: null, review: "", view_count: null },
  });

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);

  //  GET MOVIE DETAILS AND USER LOGGED DATA
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);

    axios
      .get(`/api${url.pathname}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setDetails(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [isUpdated]);

  const baseURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342";
  const placeholderImg =
    "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg";

  // Expand section to log new diary entry or view/edit previous logged data
  function handleExpand() {
    setShow(!show);
  }

  // ENTRY DATA
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    rating: null,
    review: "",
    date: new Date(),
  });

  // New object passing user data and movie data to be saved on database
  const entryData = {
    ...userData,
    title: details.tmdbDetails.title,
    year: getYear(details),
    director: getDirector(details),
    genres: getGenres(details),
    runtime: details.tmdbDetails.runtime,
  };

  // Control value on Date Picker and set it to `userData.date`
  function handleDate(date) {
    setUserData((prevValue) => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        date: date.toISOString(),
      };
    });
  }

  // Control value on Rating selector and set it to `userData.rating`
  function handleRating(event, value) {
    setUserData((prevValue) => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        rating: value,
      };
    });
  }

  // Control value on Text Area and set it to `userData.review`
  function handleReview(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setUserData((prevValue) => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        review: value,
      };
    });
  }

  // Submit entry to database and navigate to Diary
  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);

    axios.post(`/api${url.pathname}`, entryData).then((res) => {
      navigate("/diary");
    });
  }

  // Function passed to the "WatchedPanel" component to be executed on saving changes after edit entry. It changes `isUpdated` state to force a re-render of `useEffect()` and update entry data on-screen
  function handleUpdateDetails() {
    setIsUpdated(!isUpdated);
  }

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
      <Card sx={{ padding: matches ? 0 : 3, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 2 }}>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            style={{ color: "#e0e0e0" }}
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(-1);
            }}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container alignItems="center">
            {/* MOVIE TITLE & YEAR */}
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="h5">{details.tmdbDetails.title}</Typography>
              <Typography sx={{ mb: 2 }} variant="h6">
                ({getYear(details)})
              </Typography>
            </Grid>

            {/* MOVIE POSTER */}
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={matches ? 12 : 5} md={4}>
              <div style={{ textAlign: matches ? "center" : "left" }}>
                <Poster
                  source={
                    details.tmdbDetails.poster_path
                      ? baseURL + details.tmdbDetails.poster_path
                      : placeholderImg
                  }
                  altText={`${details.tmdbDetails.title} poster`}
                />
              </div>
            </Grid>

            {/* MOVIE DETAILS */}
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7} md={8}>
              <Collapse in={matches ? show : true}>
                <Credits
                  director={getDirector(details).join(", ")}
                  cast={getCast(details)}
                  genres={getGenres(details).join(", ")}
                  runtime={details.tmdbDetails.runtime}
                />
              </Collapse>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
              <Collapse in={matches ? show : true}>
                <Typography style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Synopsis</Typography>
                <Typography>{details.tmdbDetails.overview}</Typography>
              </Collapse>
            </Grid>

            {/* EXPAND SECTION BUTTON */}
            {matches ? (
              <Fab
                color="primary"
                size="small"
                aria-label="expand"
                sx={{ m: "auto", mt: 2 }}
                onClick={handleExpand}
              >
                {show ? <RemoveIcon /> : <AddIcon />}
              </Fab>
            ) : null}
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

      {/* LOG MOVIE PANEL */}

      {details.userData === undefined ? (
        <UnwatchedPanel
          date={userData.date}
          onDateChange={handleDate}
          rating={userData.rating}
          onRatingChange={handleRating}
          review={userData.review}
          onReviewChange={handleReview}
          view_count={
            details.userData === undefined ? null : details.userData.view_count
          }
          onClick={onSubmit}
        />
      ) : (
        <WatchedPanel
          date={userData.date}
          onDateChange={handleDate}
          rating={details.userData.rating}
          review={details.userData.review}
          view_count={details.userData.view_count}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          onSaveChanges={handleUpdateDetails}
        />
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Details;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, actually: this *is*, indeed, the normal React behavior. If you're navigating from one (scrollable) component to another the scrollbar isn't aware of it, since you're just changing views without reloading the whole page, and will keep it's `y` (and `x`) position. To avoid this behavior you need to manually set the scroll position on re-render, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0 });

    // Do some stuff
  }, []);
```